# Trigger validation on custom validator's scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, custom-validators

Lets say we have a custom validator with an input as the attribute's value.

```
app.directive('inputRequired', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            inputRequired: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.inputRequired = function(modelValue) {
                return !(scope.inputRequired && ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue));
            };
        }
    };
});
```

On the scope we define a variable and a function to toggle the variable's value:

```
$scope.isRequired = false;

$scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.isRequired = !$scope.isRequired;
};
```

Then we create a form where we are going to use the custom validator. We add a button to call the toggle function, too.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="someModel" input-required="isRequired"/>
    <button ng-click="toggle()">toggle</button>
</form>
```

How should this work? When the form is loaded and the scope is initialized, the value of `isRequired` is set to `false`. So the input field is not required. When we click on the toggle button, value of `isRequired`is changed to `true`. But! Validation is not triggered, although a variable on the validator's  scope was changed.

Important note: this is only an example. I know the `ng-required` directive, which implements this functionality. I need a general solution for the cases when a validator has an input and validity of the field depends on that input. If the input is changed, the field must be revalidated immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just found out a solution: add a watcher on the scope in the link function and call $validate when inputRequired change:

```
app.directive('inputRequired', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            inputRequired: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.inputRequired = function(modelValue) {
                return !(scope.inputRequired && ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue));
            };

            scope.$watch("inputRequired", function() {
                ctrl.$validate(); 
            });
        }
    };
});
```